# Is converting observable to promise good?

Tags: angular

I had a problem and solved it but would like to receive answers on several questions. 
I needed to send some data via post method with Angular HttpClient. In the beginning
I have implemented requesting on that way:

```
this.http.post<{name: string}>('some/url/address', {name}, httpOptions).subscribe((response) => {
  console.log('the request was sucessfull' + response.name);
});
```

But I noticed when I removed the subscription the request doesn't start at all. I ended converting the observable to promise like that:

```
this.http.post<{name: string}>('some/url/address', {name}, httpOptions).toPromise();
```

And it works properly. My questions are:

1. Is there better way to do that?
2. What would be negative impact of that solution?
3. Is there way to keep it as observable but request to start without subscriptions?
4. What is the reason of behavior like that? Performance tuning?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) I think your first way is fine with the subscribe.

2.) A negative impact of the promise solution is that we are letting go of functionality of the rich RxJS library and going into promise land. We can't take advantage of `map, switchMap, mergeMap, catchError, withLatestFrom` plus a bunch of other different operators given by `RxJS`. Another negative impact going the promise route is that once a promise is "given flight", it has to return with either success or error. With an observable, even though we subscribe to it and send it to "fly", we can cancel it (thereby not even making an API call at all) mid flight (before the subscription call back kicks in) using I believe `takeUntil` and an API call will not be made.

3.) This is not possible, a stream has to be subscribed for it to be emitted/"take flight".

4.) Yes, you are correct. Kind of ties in with 2 where you can get a richer experience by being able to `retry, catchError, takeUntil` and cancel the subscription.

Comment: "This is not possible, a stream has to be subscribed for it to be emitted/"take flight"." - Unfortunately I was hope this to be different. Sometimes we just don't need any subscribers. If the solution with promise doesn't have negative impact except leaving outside Rxjs world everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

`subscribe`, is the method for execution of a Observable, and if you remove that there is no execution and that is why request did not triggered at all.

and answer for other question, 
you should find out why to use observable ?

you can cancel, retry, combine them as stream, and work with other rxjs operators etc.

Answer (score 1):

*Is there better way to do that?*

Yes you should move the call to a service and it should only return only: this.http.post<{name: string}>('some/url/address', {name}, httpOptions);
Then you can call the service and subscribe to the method in your component.

*What would be negative impact of that solution?*

You should break up relevant code into parts: components/services/state etc so it's more readable and quicker to find things.

*Is there way to keep it as observable but request to start without subscriptions?*

No. You can return a promise then change the calling function to an async one and await the result of the promise.

*What is the reason of behavior like that? Performance tuning?*

No that's just how observables work. Observables have to be subscribed to in order to fire. Otherwise they just sit there and do nothing.

Comment: Re: Yes you should move the call to a service and it should only return only - I did it. This is copied from the service code.  https://github.com/gonaumov/godessessapplication/blob/master/src/app/goddess.service.ts#L19